# Prism Silverlight LoadModule and pass data

Tags: silverlight, unity-container

I'm loading a module dynamically on demand to edit a business object (let's say a customer module).

I want to then load the module and pass a customerDTO (or a primary key) to the view model. I have the OnClick command on my button to trigger my ICommand and then I load the CustomerModule:

```
    private void EditCustomer(Guid customerID)
    {
        moduleManager.LoadModule("CustommerModule");
    }
```

if I use constructor injection, Unity will instantiate a new customer DTO for me.

how do I pass the customerID to the CustomerModule?

Cheers,

Ali